# How to find $\#\{1\le x\le 5^k:5^k|(x^4-1)\}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find $\#\{1\le x\le 5^k:5^k|(x^4-1)\}$. I am not so sure how it is done, nor am I completely sure if it is about any specific $k$ or all of them together. What I did arrive at, not being really sure, is:

If $k=0$, the answer is $1$, I guess, so suppose $k>1$.
I need to have $x^4\equiv 1 \pmod{5^k}$ satisfied. I know it is for $x\equiv 1 \pmod{5^k}$. Since $5^k=5^{k-1}\cdot 4+5^{k-1}=4\cdot5^{k-1}+4\cdot5^{k-2}+5^{k-3}=4(5^{k-1}+...+5^2+5)+5\equiv 1 \pmod4$, then by a theorem taught in class, $x\equiv -1$ is a primitive root modulo $5^k$. That is, $x=5^k-1\in \{1\le x\le 5^k:5^k|(x^4-1)\}$. So $\#\{1\le x\le 5^k:5^k|(x^4-1)\}\ge 2$. I am stuck at the moment. I don't know how to find more $x$ solutions such that $x^4\equiv 1 \pmod{5^k}$. How have my argues been so far? I could really use your guiding.

Comment: First solve the case $k=1$. Then see what Hensel's Lemma tells you about bigger values of $k$.

Comment: I see, where I look at derivatives and so on?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Using that lemma, aren't I looking at $5^{k+1}$, that way not really concentrating on $\#\{1\le x\le 5^k:5^k|(x^4-1)\}$? I am afraid I have not fully understood what I am to do here. Also, I did use that lemma but at first I have $1,2,3,4$ for solutions, and finding the solutions for each one of them is tiresome and it seems superfluous. I could really use some more guiding here. :<

Comment: Each solution for $k=1$ lifts to a solution for $k=2$, for $k=3$, etc., etc. Doesn't that tell you how many solutions there are?

Comment: Using $k=1$ I can lift $4$ solutions for $k=2$ (And using Python it always seems to be four solutions.). But shouldn't I simply use induction at last?

Comment: "Using Python it always seems to be four solutions." What does Python have to do with it? Hensel! Hensel! Hensel!

Comment: It played the part of verifying.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I know how the lemma works, but I don't really understand how to show it holds for every $k$. At the most, it made me assume there are four solutions modulo every $k$. For $k=1$ that is clear. Using Hensel's lemma, I find $4$ solutions modulo $25$. How can I be sure there aren't more? Assuming $x=b$ satisfy $b^4-1\equiv 0 \pmod{5^k}$, since $4b^3\equiv 0 \iff b^3\equiv 0 \pmod {5^k}$ meaning $-1\equiv 0 \pmod {5^k}$ which is a contradiction and therefore by the lemma there is a solution modulo $5^{k+1}$. **What I am asking is**: am I allowed to do so assuming there are four?

Comment: Let $a$ be a solution modulo $5^k$. If you go through the proof of Hensel, doesn't it tell you there is exactly one $b$ such that $a+5^kb$ is a solution modulo $5^{k+1}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that if $x$ works for $k+1$ then $x$ (reduced modulo $5^k$) also works for $k$, so every solution for $k+1$ comes from a solution for $k$.

Now suppose we have a solution for $k$, that is, $a^4-1\equiv0\bmod{5^k}$. Let $b=a+5^kt$; then there is exactly one value of $t$ in $\{\,0,1,2,3,4\,\}$ such that $b$ is a solution for $k+1$. We see this as follows.

$b^4-1=a^4+4a^35^kt+5^{2k}c-1$ for some $c$, so dividing $b^4-1\equiv0\bmod{5^{k+1}}$ through by $5^k$ we get $${a^4-1\over5^k}+4a^3t\equiv0\bmod5$$ Since $a\not\equiv0\bmod5$, this equation has a unique solution $t$, and we are done.

All I have done here is I have gone through the standard proof of Hensel's Lemma for this particular congruence.

Answer (score 3):

$G=\left(\mathbb{Z}_{/(5^k\mathbb{Z})}\right)^*$ is a cyclic group having order $o(G)=4\cdot 5^{k-1}$ and we are just looking for the number of $g\in G$ such that $o(g)$ is $1$,$2$ or $4$. Assuming that $G=\langle h \rangle$, such elements are $h^{o(G)},h^{o(G)/2},h^{o(G)/4}$ and $h^{3 o(G)/4}$, so their number is:
$$ \varphi(1)+\varphi(2)+\varphi(4) = \sum_{d\mid 4}\varphi(d) = 4$$
no matter what $k$ is.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but we didn't really practice Group Theory there or at least the notations used above. I can relate because I studied Group Theory but wouldn't know how to apply it, nor would I be allowed to do so anyway...